# My ubuntu 18.04 machine will not install ruby version 2.7

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, codio

My machine has simply capped at ruby version 2.5, `ruby -v` outputs `ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`. I have tried `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, and `sudo apt-get install ruby-full`, but non of which have seemed to work.

Comment: You may find it easier to work with a version manager tool, like `rbenv`, to install and use different Ruby versions : https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#readme

Answer (score 0):

from: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-ruby-on-ubuntu-18-04
there are other ways, just visit the link to watch some of them

Example 2: By using rbenv

```
sudo apt install git curl libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev autoconf bison build-essential libyaml-dev libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm-dev

sudo apt install rbenv

echo 'export PATH="$HOME/ .rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc

echo 'eval "$(rbenv init –)"' >> ~/.bashrc 


rbenv install --list
```

and from the list select the one you want and install it

```
ex:
rbenv install rbx-2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

The supported version is usually not up to date.

A common way is using any of those Ruby version management tools, such as:

- [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) (use together with [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install))
- [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)
- [rvm](https://rvm.io/)

[Here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#managers) is the list of ruby version management tools on the official site.

If this isn't what you aren't looking for, try to [install the Ruby from source](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#building-from-source).

Lastly, you can use a [Ruby Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby) to run the Ruby script.